# Join 2 tables but have all value in condition column present in result

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables like below

| id | score1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |

| id | score2 | score3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 7 | 9 |
| 3 | 8 | 10 |
| 4 | 7 | 9 |
| 5 | 8 | 10 |

And I want to join them together to achive this result

| id | score1 | score2 | score3 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 21 |
| 3 | 6 | 8 | 10 | 24 |
| 4 | 0 | 7 | 9 | 16 |
| 5 | 0 | 8 | 10 | 18 |

How ever, i have tried all join type but the id column have null values in them, can you guys show me the solution for this? Thanks all

Comment: I removed inconsistent tags , please tag only the database you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
   coalesce(t1.id,t2.id) id
 , coalesce(t1.score1,0) score1
 , coalesce(t2.score2,0) score2
 , coalesce(t2.score3,0) score3
 , coalesce(t1.score1,0) + coalesce(t2.score2,0) + coalesce(t2.score3,0) total
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2 
 on t1.id = t2.id
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5e4d0bfe2620b1b064276ebf75891ffb)*

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT COALESCE(C.ID,C2.ID)ID,COALESCE(C.SCORE1,0)SCORE1,
 COALESCE(C2.SCORE2,0)SCORE2,COALESCE(C2.SCORE3,0)SCORE3,
 COALESCE(C.SCORE1,0)+COALESCE(C2.SCORE2,0)+COALESCE(C2.SCORE3,0) TOTAL
 FROM CTE AS C
 FULL JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C.ID=C2.ID
 ORDER BY ID
```

CTE - is yours first table(id,score1),CTE2 - second table(id,score2,score3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join in the ID.
Something like this (not tested) :

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    ISNULL(t1.score1, 0)
    ISNULL(t2.score2, 0)
    ISNULL(t2.score3, 0)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

LEFT JOIN instead of inner join or else you would only get lignes existing in t1